# EJB 3.0 When is a transaction acutally helpful

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb-3.0

What I think of is, that a transaction maintains a method to be executed. If not, there will be a rollback.
This will be useful for manipulating database. But not for doing business logic or gathering data from a service.
So I thought of declaring all these methods as @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
Since it is described as

> Use the NotSupported attribute for methods that don't need transactions. Because transactions involve overhead, this attribute may improve performance. [Tutorial Transactions](http://web.archive.org/web/20120627044942/http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction3.html)

Thank you for your help

Comment: What's the actual question? You seem to be doing alright. You're thinking about it, you're reading documentation, you're drawing reasoned conclusions. Now you test it out. What do you need help with?

Comment: I was not concerned about that fact (being right). Thanks for your reply

Comment: I have no idea what that means, "I was not concerned about that fact" :/ *what is your question?*

Comment: In which cases a transaction is important to use. Maybe you have other use cases where one can't live without it.